# Facebook public profile without graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am making a testimonial for a website and i want a user to login through facbook so that i can save his profile picture and name etc in my database

Is there any code of facebook that we can get picture and public information of the user without graph api and facebook app?

Cz now facebook need https to make a app.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any code of facebook that we can get picture and public information of the user without graph api and facebook app?

No.

The Graph API is the basis of any automated communication with Facebook’s systems, and an app id is the basis of using the API.

> Cz now facebook need https to make a app.

Rightfully so. You should not compromise your users’ security and privacy by *not* using HTTPS any more these days, especially if any kind of “login” is involved.

Getting a certificate doesn’t have to cost you much any more - Let’s Encrypt is widely available.